# Mac showing a different name at login screen

Tags: macos, security, macbook, login-screen, macos-sierra

You can see in my screenshot that my lock screen says "Hello Erwin", which is a name I use for some website account names. I am pretty sure I have nowhere entered that on my mac and I conformed it by control clicking my user → “Advanced Options” and seeing the things I entered there. Can anybody help me with that?

[image: lock screen]

Comment: if you don't know how to change that, mind sharing it with someone who might

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very trivial thing which i stumbled upon. go to **security and privacy**->**set lock message** and i was done

Comment: this was not the mac saying hello and then my name. it was a display message that you can set and i completely forgot about that and was not sure how to change it